# How do I rewrite PHP code blocks before they are passed to the interpreter?

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is write a parser for PHP that interprets whitespace instead of brackets. I can do rewriting bit and output PHP, but what I'm not sure is how best to integrate this into an application.

In an ideal world, I imagine the best thing would be to put an include at the top of the file, which in turn rewrote all the code blocks that follow it into proper PHP syntax as they are passed to the interpreter, but I am not aware that blocks of code can be passed in this way.

Another alternative is to write it as a server extension, but I would prefer not to do this, as it makes it less accessible.

Is there an easy way to architect this?

Comment: Such extension already exists and is called "Python", although it does not use PHP at all.
Really, you are trying to build an incompatible version of PHP language. If you really have to, write a precompiler that transforms YOUR version of WHITESPACE-PHP into regular PHP before you release such code or put it to any server.

Comment: Hooray for the epic effort to bring php to the future. unfortunaly I can't advice you with the how to - maybe facebook hiphop project (compiling php to c++) would be helpful (althought different). In the whitespace language I'm using: python, I could do it with a Decorator, but I don't think PHP has that feature

Comment: Take a look at ircmaxell's [PHPPHP](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP) for an example of writing a PHP parser in PHP

Comment: Hey Sven- my approach would be analogous to coffeescript; ultimately, just cosmetic changes. The language would remain structurally the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this with [Stream Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php).

With that you can basically read and re-write any code that is read by PHP ***before*** it is actually interpretted. with `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `include`, `require`, `file_get_contents()` etc.

So in your case you could listen for any file that is `require(_once)` or `include(_once)` and do with the code you like. You will get the entire code in a variable and with that you can simply do all sorts of replacements in strings with regex and what not.

The only downside is, is that your `index.php` can't make use of this method since it is ***not*** catched by any `include` or `require`. But any other code file that is included from there can be catched by the `stream wrapper`.

Here is an article about a plugin system that uses that method. Maybe it can be of any help.

http://phpmyweb.net/2012/04/26/write-an-awesome-plugin-system-in-php/

In there you'll also find a link to a guthub page with the source of the plugin code. In there you can basically see how to setup your `Stream Wrapper` class. From there on you can make up your own code as you do not have to intercept any method calls etc. like the plugin is doing.

Comment: You know, i think that might just be it. The index.php limitation is not a big deal, I think that's acceptable. I'll take a closer look at the source here, but it looks very promising! Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your include idea would work as described. Since the code would be missing braces, it probably would not make it through the normal PHP parser without throwing a 500 error. So the file you want to include could never do its work.

The opposite approach might work. Write a parser script and have it read and execute your "whitespace" PHP files.

URLs might look like this: **mydomain.com/my-parsing-script.php?file=script/to/parse.php**

Then you'd edit .htaccess to rewrite all your URLs to make that stuff invisible to the user.

The parsing script would simply open the "whitespace" file and do some regex magic before passing the script to eval();